# Room: Cannot use unbound fields in entities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've found literally 0 articles/threads about this error on the internet so I'm absolutely clueless, so here it goes.

I have a class A and a class B.

class A is having an ArrayList of class B instances like this:

```
@Entity
class A {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id = 0
    var listOfB: ArrayList<B>
}
```

And here it goes the B class:

```
@Entity
class B {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id = 0
    var specificDate: Date? = null
}
```

Whenever I try to run the project I get the following error message:

```
Cannot use unbound fields in entities.
```

Which points exactly to the ArrayList of B instances inside the A class.

What may be causing this?

Comment: Room is not that kind of database.  The second array has to go in its own table.

Comment: And how? Or is there any "that kind of database" you can suggest?

Comment: Room is table database.  You need a hierarchical database.  I would just make a view  create view c as  select * from a join b on a.id = b.id and push  on.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi
Change the ArrayList to List. the magic will happen.

```
@Entity
class A {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id = 0
    var listOfB: List<B>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try update room dependencies to newer version

```kotlin
room = "2.6.0-rc01"

androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "room" }

it fixed the issues in my case
```

Answer (score 0):

An Entity has two purposes:

1. It defines the columns of a table in the database.
2. An instance of the entity represents one row of an element in that database, which can be given to you as a query result, or you can pass to Room to add or edit a row in the corresponding table.

SQL/SQLite doesn't have the concept of a table column where the type is another table or list of rows from another table, so what you're defining doesn't make sense. (Incidentally, you cannot use Lists of any type for a column type in a table. You can only use primitive type classes in an Entity class since that's all that SQL supports.)

Instead, you must define a relationship between your two tables. In this case, you can remove the list property from your class A. I'm not sure if you're trying to define a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, but you can look at the Room [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many) for an example of how to set up relationships.

Basically, if a B can only be a member of a single A at a time, B should reference an A row ID in one of its columns, and you have a one-to-many relationship. Room will let you create a third data class (not an entity) to define the relationship in a natural way that looks similar to your example class A and can be returned in queries.

If B can belong to multiple different A's, then you have a many-to-many relationship, which is more complicated. A third table (Entity class) has to be defined to link the relationships together.

Comment: Don't like long answers too much like a bot.

Comment: @danny117, Should I write a shorter one that’s less helpful? That's the first time in my 12 years here that I've been downvoted for being too thorough.

Comment: Idk.  I'm just a hater of verbose answers.  The actual problem is op code is not supported afaik in room.

Comment: @danny117, 9 times out of 10, if you write a two sentence answer that just tells someone why something doesn't work, they follow up by asking in the comments, "Then what is the workaround?". Most people actually want a solution to their problem, not just to be told they're wrong. The point of this site is to become an information source and actually help people resolve issues.

Comment: Yep a solution  would include take out reference to b in a

Answer (score 0):

Tenfour04 is correct. Dont store a list in SQL.
You can store the list-data in SQL by storing the list of objects as a string, using GSON to create that string.

In your project gravel file:

```
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
```

Create a TypeConverter to convert the list to a GSON string.

```
class MyConverters {
  var gson: Gson = Gson()

  @TypeConverter
  fun stringToBList(data: String?): List<B> {
    if (data == null) {
      return ArrayList<B>()
    }
    val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<B?>?>() {}.getType()
    return gson.fromJson(data, listType)
  }

  @TypeConverter
  fun bListToString(b: List<B?>?): String {
    return gson.toJson(b)
  }
}
```

Register the typeconverter in your app database:

```
@Database(entities = [A::class, B::class, ], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(MyConverters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
.... }
```

Then the field may be added to an Entity:

```
@Entity
class A {

  @ColumnInfo(name = "items")
  var items: List<B> = ArrayList<B>()
```

This pattern (similar) could also be used if you want the List to contain the primary B keys, like e.g. an Ingeger List.