# SQL Check if single ID is contained in list of IDS saved in database

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I am writing SQL query in my android app which I though will work but doesn't. So it goes like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ${AppDatabase.GAME_TABLE} WHERE :collectionId IN (themesIds)")
    fun getAllGamesForCollection(collectionId: String): List<GameEntity>
```

In my Game_Table entity, themeIds field is represented like this:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "themesIds")
    var themesIds: List<String> = mutableListOf()
```

What I wanted is to check what games contain "collectionId" (single string that I send in my code) in their themesIds (List of strings that contain different Ids and are saved in database). I use room library (just for the records).

Why is this not working?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75133104/room-cannot-use-unbound-fields-in-entities

Comment: @user39950 pardon me but I don't see any connection between these 2 questions. Even more, my code does not cause any crash, it just does not return any value for this query. Also I am not using list of objects, but list of primitive data in my entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `WHERE instr(themesIds,:collectionId)` or `WHERE themesIds LIKE '%'||:collectionId||'%'`.

This does rely upon the stored representation of the List (see below) containing the textual values *(if the List is converted to a bytestream then the above would not work without converting the bytes)*.

However, both are prone to other unwanted matches; for example `AAA` would also find `AAABBB` `BBBAAACCC` as `AAA` exists in all of these.

The likely reason that IN is not working is that it expects the value after IN to either be a comma separated list of values or the result of a select query. It is unlikely that the data (*List of strings that contain different Ids and are saved in database*) are just such a CSV it will be a single value holding all of the values of the list.

- based upon the the bolded and italicised quote from the question.

If the weakness mentioned above is an issue then you would have to be more specific about exactly what ***List of strings that contain different Ids and are saved in database*** is in fact; it cannot be a List. That is SQLite (the database which Room is a wrapper around) does not store lists it stores single values per column which may reflect an object (List).

- Say the List consists of the elements

  - The
  - Quick
  - Brown
  - Fox

Then the 4 values have to be represented by a single value.

If that single value were `The,Quick,Brown,Fox` (CSV) then IN would not work as it is a single value (if it were 'The','Quick','Brown','Fox' then it would work but to get that from the column would be quite complex (a recursive subquery that splits the string)).

However, there is no reason why the representation could instead be `The;Quick;Brown;Fox` in which case IN would not work.

- For Room this would depend upon the TypeConverter used to store the List.

You may wish to edit your question to include an example of the actual data stored in the themesIds column (App Inspection can be used for this)

Comment: man that is great explanation of the situation. I tried with WHERE instr(themesIds,:collectionId) and it works like charm. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that would, from a relational database perspective (e.g. SQLite which is what Room is a wrapper around), be considered better/proper (and what the comment in your question is trying to point out).

That is rather than embed a list, the list should really be another table that has a relationship to the table that had the embedded list. As such rather than a list of themeId's a **Game** table and a **Theme** table (which you may well have). As a Theme may be used by many Games and that a Game could have many themes. The relationship would be a many-many reltionship.

A many-many relationship typically has another table that has two core columns. One to reference one table, the other to reference the other table. The two columns would form a composite unique index of both columns (composite primary key). Thus any game could reference(map/link ....) any Theme.

Such a table has many names reference table, mapping table, associative table ....

With such a setup using `IN` could then be used.

To demonstrate consider the following code that reflects some of what can be gleaned from you question.

First a version of the **AppDatabase** class (expanded to include ALL component names table and columns and also expanded to cater for the mapping table, hopefully the names should be quite clear):-

```
class AppDatabase {
    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "game.db"
        const val GAME_TABLE = "game"
        const val GAME_ID_COL = "${GAME_TABLE}${BaseColumns._ID}"
        const val GAME_THEMEIDS_COL = "${GAME_TABLE}_themids"

        const val THEME_TABLE = "theme"
        const val THEME_ID_COL = "${THEME_TABLE}${BaseColumns._ID}"
        const val THEME_NAME_COL = "${ THEME_TABLE}_themename"

        /* The Mapping table */
        const val GAME_THEME_MAP_TABLE = "game_theme_map"
        const val GAME_THEME_MAP_GAME_ID_COL = "${GAME_THEME_MAP_TABLE}_${GAME_ID_COL}"
        const val GAME_THEME_MAP_THEME_ID_COL ="${GAME_THEME_MAP_TABLE}_${THEME_ID_COL}"
    }
}
```

- Note that the above ensures that all column names are unique (**Room without complaining can juxtapose values between like named columns**).
- As can be seen 3 tables Game, Theme and the mapping table between the two.

For the demo the **Game** table is:-

```
@Entity(tableName = AppDatabase.GAME_TABLE)
data class Game(
    @ColumnInfo(name = AppDatabase.GAME_ID_COL)
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    //@ColumnInfo(name = AppDatabase.GAME_THEMEIDS_COL)
    //val themeIds: List<String>
)
```

- note that the **themeIds** has been commented out as it is not needed

**Theme** table is:-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = AppDatabase.THEME_TABLE,

    /* Make the Theme name unique */
    indices = [
        Index(AppDatabase.THEME_NAME_COL, unique = true)
    ]
)
data class Theme(
    @ColumnInfo(name = AppDatabase.THEME_ID_COL)
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = AppDatabase.THEME_NAME_COL)
    val themeName: String
)
```

- Note sure if you have a name column but this has been added anyway.
- Due to the way that SQLite works and it's more efficient handling of the **rowid** the **id** will be an alias of the **rowid**. Even though, as will be seen, the inefficient use of autoGenerate has not been used (although ids will be automatically generated unless a value other than null is used for the id).
- Note sure if wanted but the Theme name must be unique (to demonstrate how to do this in Room without the column being the primary key (string primary keys are less efficient))

Now the Mapping Table **GameThemeMap** (map used just because it is shorter):-

```
/* caters for a many-many relationship */
/* i.e. many games can map to a theme, many themes can map to a them */
/* no need to store lists*/
@Entity(tableName = AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_TABLE,
    primaryKeys = [AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_GAME_ID_COL,AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_THEME_ID_COL],
    /* Optional but enforces Referential Integrity */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity =  Game::class,
            parentColumns = [AppDatabase.GAME_ID_COL],
            childColumns = [AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_THEME_ID_COL],
            /* Optional within Foreign Key but helps to automatically maintain Referential Integrity */
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, /* deletes children if parent is deleted */
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE /* updates children if parent mapped column is updated */
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Theme::class,
            parentColumns = [AppDatabase.THEME_ID_COL],
            childColumns = [AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_THEME_ID_COL],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class GameThemeMap(
    @ColumnInfo(name = AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_GAME_ID_COL)
    val gameIdMap: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true, name = AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_THEME_ID_COL)
    /* Index will speed up access via themes id column, but will have an overhead when inserting */
    val themeIdMao: Long
)
```

- hopefully the comments explain what may appear to be quite complex for a 2 column table

As you will probably expect to be able to get a Game with it's Themes then the POJO for doing so **GameWithThemes**:-

```
data class GameWithThemes(
    @Embedded
    val game: Game,
    @Relation(
        entity = Theme::class,
        parentColumn = AppDatabase.GAME_ID_COL,
        entityColumn = AppDatabase.THEME_ID_COL,
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = GameThemeMap::class,
            parentColumn = AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_GAME_ID_COL,
            entityColumn = AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_THEME_ID_COL
        )
    )
    val themes: List<Theme>
)
```

- The above allows Room to simulate the JOIN's used get related data.

Some @Dao functions including two ways to select the games via the **collectionId** one using IN the other using a a comparison of the Theme's id extracted via a JOIN, so **TheDAOs**:-

```
@Dao
interface TheDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(game: Game): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(theme: Theme): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(gameThemeMap: GameThemeMap): Long

    @Transaction /* recommended as Room executes subqueries to get the Themes for the Game (note that it gets ALL themes for a game) */
    @Query("SELECT ${AppDatabase.GAME_TABLE}.* " +
            "FROM ${AppDatabase.GAME_TABLE} " +
            "JOIN ${AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_TABLE} " +
            "ON  ${AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_TABLE}.${AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_GAME_ID_COL} = ${AppDatabase.GAME_TABLE}.${AppDatabase.GAME_ID_COL} " +
            "AND :collectionId = ${AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_TABLE}.${AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_THEME_ID_COL}")
    fun getGamesWithThemesViaJoin(collectionId: Long): List<GameWithThemes>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${AppDatabase.GAME_TABLE} WHERE :collectionId IN(SELECT ${AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_THEME_ID_COL} FROM ${AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_TABLE} WHERE ${AppDatabase.GAME_THEME_MAP_GAME_ID_COL}=${AppDatabase.GAME_ID_COL})")
    fun getGamesWithThemesViaIN(collectionId: Long): List<GameWithThemes>

    @Query("SELECT ${AppDatabase.THEME_ID_COL} FROM ${AppDatabase.THEME_TABLE} WHERE ${AppDatabase.THEME_NAME_COL}=:themeName")
    fun getThemeIdFromThemeName(themeName: String): Long
}
```

- hopefully the function names should say what is going on

To tie all the above the @Database annotated abstract class **TheDatabase**:-

```
@Database(entities = [Game::class,Theme::class,GameThemeMap::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getTheDAOs(): TheDAOs

    companion object {
        var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- `.allowMainThreadQueries` for convenience and brevity

Last to actually demonstrate some code in an activity that adds 5 Themes, 5 Games and various Themes mapped to the games.

- Game 1 has 2 Themes mapped to it 1 and 2
- Game 2 has 2 other Themes 3 and 4
- Game 3 has 4 Themes 1,2,3 and 4
- Game 4 has 1 Theme 5
- Game 5 has no Themes

After inserting the data 2 sets of 5 queries are run and the extracted GameWithThemes are output to the log via the **`logGameWithThemes`** method.

The activity **MainActivity**:-

```
const val TAG = "DBINFO"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: TheDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getTheDAOs()

        val t1Id = dao.insert(Theme(themeName = "Theme 1"))
        val t2Id = dao.insert(Theme(themeName = "Theme 2"))
        val t3Id = dao.insert(Theme(themeName = "Theme 3"))
        val t4Id = dao.insert(Theme(themeName = "Theme 4"))
        val t5Id = dao.insert(Theme(themeName = "Theme 5"))

        val game1Id =dao.insert(Game())
        val game2Id = dao.insert(Game())
        val game3Id = dao.insert(Game())
        val game4Id = dao.insert(Game())
        val game5Id = dao.insert(Game())

        dao.insert(GameThemeMap(game1Id,t1Id))
        dao.insert(GameThemeMap(game1Id,t2Id))
        dao.insert(GameThemeMap(game2Id,t3Id))
        dao.insert(GameThemeMap(game2Id,t4Id))
        dao.insert(GameThemeMap(game3Id,t1Id))
        dao.insert(GameThemeMap(game3Id,t2Id))
        dao.insert(GameThemeMap(game3Id,t3Id))
        dao.insert(GameThemeMap(game3Id,t4Id))
        dao.insert(GameThemeMap(game4Id,t5Id))

        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaIN(t1Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_IN_TID_$t1Id")
        }
        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaIN(t2Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_IN_TID_$t2Id")
        }
        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaIN(t3Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_IN_TID_$t3Id")
        }
        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaIN(t4Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_IN_TID_$t4Id")
        }
        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaIN(t5Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_IN_TID_$t5Id")
        }
        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaJoin(t1Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_JN_TID_$t1Id")
        }
        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaJoin(t2Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_JN_TID_$t2Id")
        }
        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaJoin(t3Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_JN_TID_$t3Id")
        }
        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaJoin(t4Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_JN_TID_$t4Id")
        }
        for (g in dao.getGamesWithThemesViaJoin(t5Id)) {
            logGameWithThemes(g,"_JN_TID_$t5Id")
        }
    }
    fun logGameWithThemes(gameWithThemes: GameWithThemes, suffix: String) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for(t in gameWithThemes.themes) {
            sb.append("\n\tTheme ID is ${t.id} Theme name is ${t.themeName}")
        }
        Log.d(TAG+suffix,"Game ID is ${gameWithThemes.game.id} it has ${gameWithThemes.themes.size} THEMES. They are:-${sb}")
    }
}
```

When run (only intended to be run the once to demonstrate) then the output to the log is:-

```
2023-01-18 22:22:04.903 D/DBINFO_IN_TID_1: Game ID is 1 it has 2 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.903 D/DBINFO_IN_TID_1: Game ID is 3 it has 4 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.906 D/DBINFO_IN_TID_2: Game ID is 1 it has 2 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.906 D/DBINFO_IN_TID_2: Game ID is 3 it has 4 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.910 D/DBINFO_IN_TID_3: Game ID is 2 it has 2 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.910 D/DBINFO_IN_TID_3: Game ID is 3 it has 4 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.916 D/DBINFO_IN_TID_4: Game ID is 2 it has 2 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.916 D/DBINFO_IN_TID_4: Game ID is 3 it has 4 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.921 D/DBINFO_IN_TID_5: Game ID is 4 it has 1 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 5 Theme name is Theme 5
        
        
        
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.926 D/DBINFO_JN_TID_1: Game ID is 1 it has 2 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.926 D/DBINFO_JN_TID_1: Game ID is 3 it has 4 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.931 D/DBINFO_JN_TID_2: Game ID is 1 it has 2 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.931 D/DBINFO_JN_TID_2: Game ID is 3 it has 4 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.937 D/DBINFO_JN_TID_3: Game ID is 2 it has 2 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.937 D/DBINFO_JN_TID_3: Game ID is 3 it has 4 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.940 D/DBINFO_JN_TID_4: Game ID is 2 it has 2 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.940 D/DBINFO_JN_TID_4: Game ID is 3 it has 4 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 1 Theme name is Theme 1
        Theme ID is 2 Theme name is Theme 2
        Theme ID is 3 Theme name is Theme 3
        Theme ID is 4 Theme name is Theme 4
        
        
2023-01-18 22:22:04.945 D/DBINFO_JN_TID_5: Game ID is 4 it has 1 THEMES. They are:-
        Theme ID is 5 Theme name is Theme 5
```

i.e. the expected results (noting that when using @Relation that Room retrieves ALL children of the parent) and importantly that both methods (IN and JOIN) produce the same results.

In comparison to using `instr` or `LIKE %???%` the above method should be far more efficient (faster) as full table scans are avoided (no other way when using `instr` or `LIKE %????%` but full table scans as every row has to be processed/checked).

Furthermore the comparisons are EXACT.

Comment: Thanks one more time. This one goes more to details hehe